# Dependency hsqld error geotools 17.1?

Tags: java, geotools

*from the possible duplicate question already asked** i did do a 
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=hsqldb , the the results are:

```
[INFO] foo-io:foo-io:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.geotools:gt-epsg-hsql:jar:17.1:compile
[INFO]    \- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.3.0:compile
```

I've seen this issue alot when using geo-tools..however i cannot seem to resolvethis.  I keep getting a dependency error when using geo tools...i've checked the dependency tree and can see no issues..

```
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building foo-io 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ boundaries-io ---
[INFO] foo-io:foo-io:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.geotools:gt-epsg-hsql:jar:17.1:compile
[INFO]    \- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ----------------------
```

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

```
org.hsqldb.DatabaseURL.parseURL(Ljava/lang/String;ZZ)Lorg/hsqldb/persist/HsqlProperties;
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.DirectEpsgFactory.getConnection(DirectEpsgFactory.java:3302)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:436)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.getBackingStore(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:133)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.BufferedAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(BufferedAuthorityFactory.java:235)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:119)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAvailable(FactoryRegistry.java:667)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAcceptable(FactoryRegistry.java:501)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry$1.filter(FactoryRegistry.java:192)
    at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.advance(ServiceRegistry.java:821)
    at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.<init>(ServiceRegistry.java:815)
    at javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.getServiceProviders(ServiceRegistry.java:516)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceProviders(FactoryRegistry.java:197)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getFactories(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:180)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getCRSAuthorityFactories(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:455)
    at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.getBackingFactory(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:89)
    at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.<init>(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:69)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.getAuthorityFactory(CRS.java:263)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.decode(CRS.java:525)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.decode(CRS.java:453)
    at com.vanitysoft.boundaries.domain.dao.impl.USPostalDAOImpl.createRadiusPolygon(USPostalDAOImpl.java:352)
    at com.vanitysoft.boundaries.domain.manager.impl.USPostalManagerImplTest.testFindPostalByRadisCircle(USPostalManagerImplTest.java:153)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hsqldb.DatabaseURL.parseURL maven runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652422/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-hsqldb-databaseurl-parseurl-maven-runtime)

Comment: thanks, but it was never 'solved' by any of the answers.

Comment: then you'll need to provide a MVE including the pom.xml file

Comment: sorry..the "MVE"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work using gt-epsg-wkt instead of hsql.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
    <artifactId>gt-epsg-wkt</artifactId>
    <version>${geotools.version}</version>
</dependency
```